# Type check of user input and exclude negative numbers with exceptions

Tags: python, exception, input, logical-operators

I have the following method, which I use to take inputs from the user and handle it via exceptions until they fullfill the criteria.

```py
    def enter_data(self, message: str, typ: type):
        while True:
            try:
                v = typ(input(message))
                if isinstance(v, int) or isinstance(v, float) and v < 0:
                    raise ValueError
            except ValueError:
                print(f"Thats not an {typ}! or you have entered a negative")
                continue
            else:
                break
        return v
```

This is the way I call it

```py
 def add_item_interaction(self) -> None:
   add_item_num = self.enter_data("What is the new items #?\n", int)
   add_item_price = self.enter_data("What is the new items price?\n", float)
   add_item_quant = self.enter_data("What is the new items quantity?\n", int)
   add_name = self.enter_data("What is the new items name?\n", str)
```

This doesn't seem to work for any type entered, no matter if it is a negative or matches what I specify.

Any Help Here? I know I must be close.

For example:

When I run `add_item_num = self.enter_data("What is the new items #?\n", int)`, and input 1, I get: "Thats not an int!", even though the input is an int, and positive, so it should not trigger the `if isinstance(...)` statement

Comment: I think this function is trying to do too much, but you could accept a `validator` argument which expects a function which will be passed the value and returns `True` or `False`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga could you elaborate further on this? Sorta confused.

Comment: Can you specify you input and error. From my perspective the last code block works.

Comment: @Daraan added input/output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This boils down to a `True or False and False = True` problem.
Without paranthesis this is executed like this

```
or(True, and(False,False))
```

The first value is instantly returned and the others are not evaluated.

Your idea is perfect you just need to add the parantheses

```py
   def enter_data(self, message: str, typ: type):
        while True:
            try:
                v = typ(input(message))
                if (isinstance(v, int) or isinstance(v, float)) and v < 0:
                    raise ValueError
            except ValueError:
                print(f"Thats not an {typ}! or you have entered a negative")
                continue
            else:
                break
        return v
```